# Set collapsing priority without applying flex to CSS items?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<ul>` element that is styled to list its inner `<li>` elements horizontally:

> one is the 1st number | two is the 2nd number | three is the 3rd number | four is the 4th number

This works fine for shorter content, but these "cells" need to collapse with varying priorities if there's not enough space to display them ***without wrapping***.

**...Something like this:**

> one is the first number | two is the... | three is the... | f...

So, the first cell should always display 100% of its content, the second two cells should display ~40-50% (fluidly or as a hard-coded width/percentage), and the 4th cell can take up whatever's left (if anything)... without overflowing the parent container's bounds.

Oh, and these items all need to be equally **vertically-aligned** for aesthetics.

**Possible to do cleanly without flex/JS?** I'm not sure. The idea is to create something visually appealing that can display as much information from the listed sections as possible within that single line, with the first one *always* displaying all of its content without ellipsis/wrapping/overflow and taking the highest priority in that line.

---

**EDIT:** I just want to clarify that setting `min-width` won't work here because the content could render in less than the `min-width`. (consider "abc" instead of "two is the..." ... That should only take the space of "abc" for `<li>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this what I can conjure up with `flexbox` - I guess this will get you started:

1. A `flexbox` of `ul` with `white-space:nowrap` to all the flex children to keep the text content in a single line.
2. Added `ellipsis` to the flex children except the first one as per your requirement.
3. The magic here is done by:

   ```
   ul > li:first-child {
     flex: 0 1 auto;
   }
   ul > li:nth-child(2) {
     flex: 0 1 auto;
   }
   ul > li:nth-child(3) {
     flex: 0 2 auto;
   }
   ul > li:nth-child(4) {
     flex: 0 3 auto;
   }
   ```

   a.   For the first flex child, we disable `flex-grow`

   b.   For the other flex children, we use relative `flex`ing.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul > li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px;
}
ul > li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
ul > li:not(:first-child) {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul > li:first-child {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
ul > li:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
ul > li:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 0 2 auto;
}
ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 0 3 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one is the 1st number</li>
  <li>two is the 2nd number</li>
  <li>three is the 3rd number</li>
  <li>four is the 4th number</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks OK but the 2nd block has a bunch of extra space after it for me...

Comment: @BenGuild check it now - I guess I've nailed it!

Comment: Hmm, two questions. How does it handle situations where like the 2nd block has a lot of text, but the 3rd only has a little? How do you set the ratio of what's displayed based on a priority? — Also, how does this fall back to older browsers?

Comment: So, this seems to work pretty well, except if one of the center two sections is unusually long. Ideally it should show a reasonable amount of both, versus just sections 1 and 2 while pushing 3 and 4 to their bare minimum. Is this possible in the same configuration?

Comment: It might be possible if like, sections 2 and 3 had the same `flex-grow` priority or something... with the 4th one having a lower one and the 1st one having a higher one. Not sure.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted this answer for now! Thanks. I do wish there was a way to prioritize (or "weight") the 2nd or 3rd cell for example, but maybe that's best done in code.

Comment: Today morning I'd a fresh look on it - but I can't get it any better than it is now - maybe this is the best thing AFAIK that is possible with flexbox. You may want to open the question so that someone has a better solution? :) Of course, I'd like to get an upvote instead!

Comment: I think it's OK for now, but if you have a follow-up let me know :)

Comment: Thanks ! Will let you know if I come across a better solution :)