# How to shrink large flex-box children first?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to build a breadcrumb control for a web application. The text in each flex-box child should be truncated whenever the space in the container is not large enough to display everything. The problem is shorter children are shrinked along with larger children and become quickly unreadable.

E.g. 3 short children look perfectly fine:

[image]

But once one child has more text everything will be shrinked:

[image]

**Is there a way to configure flex box that it shrinks larger children to the same size as smaller children first?**

Ideally the example should look like this:

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Link A
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link B
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link C this is a really long link with lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: another [interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218508/set-collapsing-priority-with-flex-css-items/40219465#40219465)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `flexbox` I guess the option is to make the *flex items* stretch by an equal amount by giving `flex: 1` to the `child` element (but this has the downside that the `child` items do not have *auto* width) - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Link A
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link B
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link C this is a really long link with lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```

Using [`CSS Grid layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), you can achieve this easily:

1. Use `display: grid` on the container.
2. Add `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)` to make three columns of auto width

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid; /* defines a grid container */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto); /* all three columns with auto width */
  width: 600px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Link A
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link B
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link C this is a really long link with lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set width to childs?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
.child {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;  
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Link A</div>
  <div class="child">Link B</div>
  <div class="child">Link C this is a really long link with lots of text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **minimum width of smaller children** which you want to display full

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
.child {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width:86px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Link A</div>
  <div class="child">Link B</div>
  <div class="child">Link C this is a really long link with lots of text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The min-width is depending on the length of the untruncated text. Is there a  way to retrieve this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are searching for `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow` and `flex-basis`, for more [read this](https://medium.com/@tiffnogueira/understanding-flex-shrink-flex-grow-and-flex-basis-and-using-these-properties-to-their-full-e4b4afd2c930)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;/*I changed this just for testing*/
}

.child {
  flex: 1 1 33%;/*Add this line*/
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    Link A
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link B
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    Link C this is a really long link with lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```