# How to orderly shrink table columns

Tags: html, css, css-tables

My users will visit my web page with monitors, ranging from 11' to 15', so I hope to have my page adaptive to screen resolution.

I have a `table` with several columns. With screen width getting smaller, the columns can shrink to `ellipsis` (the first word with 3 dots) by the order I specify.

For example, I have a `table` of `Employee` with columns `id`, `name`, `department`, `title`, `manager` and `on-board date`.

As the screen width gets smaller, I want column `on-board date` to the first shrink with others unchanged till `ellipsis` minimum width. Then column `manager` shrinks, then column `title` shrinks.

Hopefully, I can achieve this without a media query.

Comment: possible guidance with *flexboxes* [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218508/set-collapsing-priority-with-flex-css-items/40219465#40219465) and [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902567/how-to-shrink-large-flex-box-children-first/54903027#54903027)...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the text inside `<td>` within a span so that ellipsis can take effect.
Further more, you will also need to set `table-layout:fixed` so that set a fixed table/cell width for all columns.

See below example

```css
table{
table-layout: fixed;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%; /*Remove if not required*/
}
table td, table th{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table td span{
display: block;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
  /* Required for text-overflow to do anything */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr> 
<th> <span> ID  </span> </th>
<th> <span> Username </span> </th>
<th> <span> Email Address </span> </th>
<th> <span> Designation </span> </th>
<th> <span> Address </span> </th>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> <span> 01  </span> </td>
<td> <span> Username01 </span> </td>
<td> <span> longemailddress@domain.com </span> </td>
<td> <span> long long designation </span> </td>
<td> <span> Some street, Address, City, state, Country </span> </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> <span> 02  </span> </td>
<td> <span> Username01 </span> </td>
<td> <span> longemailddress@domain.com </span> </td>
<td> <span> long long designation </span> </td>
<td> <span> Some street, Address, City, state, Country </span> </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td> <span> 03  </span> </td>
<td> <span> Username01 </span> </td>
<td> <span> longemailddress@domain.com </span> </td>
<td> <span> long long designation </span> </td>
<td> <span> Some street, Address, City, state, Country </span> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

And if you want to adjust table widths based on column orders you can use CSS pseudo classes. For example use this to increase width of 2nd column

```
table td:nth-child(2){
    width: 150px;
}
```

You can also use CSS flex box to handle your table layout adjustment.

Comment: columns in your answer are shrinking together not by order :(

Comment: Yes you will need to remove `table layout: fixed` and then add width using nth child selector